# Imagining people nude is a zina of heart but the punishment of zina is of 80 lashes?? Does imagining nude has that punishment

Tags: punishment, zina

Asslam o alaikum to all of my brothers and sisters... Well i have heard many times that imagining people nude is zina of heart watching porn is zina of eyes and hearing sex voices is zina of ear(sorry for this language) but it was written that punishment of zina is 80 lashes. So i mean 80 lashes of punishment is only for those who had sex with someone except his wife??? Is there any punishment for these zina??(for heart zina nd eye zina and ear zina as i have already mentioned) how are these are zina even without having sex with someone??? Or there are many types of zina???

Answer (score 1):

No, there are some sins/crimes in Islam (mostly related to human rights) has worldly punishments but many other sins even bigger has no worldly punishments but you'll start getting punishment immediately after death.

So, zina of eyes and zina of ears means it takes you to which is real zina (sexual intercourse). As prevention Islam call these you can say smaller zina.

Answer (score 0):

“The fornicatress and the fornicator, flog each of them with a hundred stripes. Let not pity withhold you in their case, in a punishment prescribed by Allaah, if you believe in Allaah and the Last Day. And let a party of the believers witness their punishment”

[al-Noor 24:2]

It was narrated from Jaabir that a man from (the tribe of) Aslam came to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) when he was in the mosque and he said, “I have committed adultery.”  The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) turned his face away from him. The man came to that side to which the Prophet had turned his face, and testified against himself four times. The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said, "Are you mad?” He said, “No.” The Prophet said, “Are you married?" He said, "Yes.” So he commanded that he be stoned in the Musalla (Eid prayer place). When the stones troubled him, he ran away, until he was caught in al-Harrah and killed.

Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 4969; Muslim, 1691.

there is no hadd punishment for imagining nude people.

but it is haraam

It was narrated that Ibn Mas’ood (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “No woman should look at or touch another woman to describe her to her husband as if he can see her.”

(Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 4942).